# Heinz inequality for positive operators

Tags: operator-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be bounded positive operators over a **real** Hilbert space $H$, i.e., $\langle A x,x \rangle \geq 0$ for all $x$ (and similarly for $B$).
I further have $$\|A x \| \leq \| B x\| \qquad (1)$$ for all $x \in H$, and I would want to compare the fractional powers of $A$ and $B$, namely I expect we then have the existence of some $C>0$ (maybe $C=1$) such that for all $x$ and $\alpha \in (0,1)$,
\begin{equation}
\label{2}
\|A^\alpha x \| \leq C \| B^\alpha x\| \qquad (2).
\end{equation}
This is very similar to the Heinz inequality that states $A \leq B \implies A^\alpha \leq B^\alpha$ in the sense of positive operators.
Inequality (1) certainly implies $|A| \leq |B|$ where $|A| = (A^\ast A)^{1/2}$, but the Heinz inequality leads to $|A|^\alpha \leq |B|^\alpha$ which does not yield the expected result (2) unless $A$ and $A^\star$ commute (same for $B$ and $B^\ast$), which is not the case I am faced with.

Does the expected inequality (2) still hold true? If so, does anyone have a good reference? If other conditions are required to obtain the expected result, I am also interested in such sufficient conditions.

Comment: On a complex Hilbert space every bounded positive operator is self-adjoint.

Comment: Thank you, I have edited the question.

Comment: Note that, by positive, I do mean $\langle Ax, x \rangle \geq 0$ for all $x$ and not more (as far as I can tell, this is the common definition for operators, which is not aligned with the one used for mere matrices)